# reset a variable for a reusable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, return

I have a bit of code that counts how many objects are in the returned json and gives me the total number.

```
loadCountSetOne = 0;
$.each(dataSetOne.user.customers, function(key, val) {  
    loads =  Object.keys(val.loads).length;
    loadCountSetOne = loadCountSetOne + loads;
    console.log(loadCountSetOne);
});
```

This works fine, but since I'll need to count these a bunch of times I thought I'd move it into it's own function and call it when I need it with something like `counter(val.loads);`

```
count = 0;  
function counter(itemToCount) {
    result =  Object.keys(itemToCount).length;
    count = count + result;
    console.log(itemToCount, result, count);
    return count;
}
```

When I call the function the 1st time I get the right result. When I call it again it adds the 2nd result to the 1st and so on.

My understanding is that that is what it's supposed to do, but not what I need it to do. I tried resetting the value for `count` is various places but it didn't work.

Is there a way to make this function give me a result based on the number of objects in `itemToCount` each time it's called?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `Object.keys(val)` be `Object.keys(itemToCount)`?

Comment: Yeah it should, sorry, been playing around too much from the original and missed to fix this in the question.

Comment: It might help - the value of val.loads in this example is key0 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] key1 [Object, Object] and the desired result is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the `counter()` function itself, since it has no way of distinguishing the first call (which should reset the variable) with subsequent calls. You could pass the array index, and it could reset the total when the index is `0`, but this is not a good general solution because you might want to use the function in other ways.

You just need to reset the variable before the `$.each()` loop:

```
count = 0;
$.each(dataSetOne.user.customers, function(key, val) {
    counter(val.loads);
});
```

Or you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is designed for accumulating values.

```
function counter(total, itemToCount) {
    var result =  Object.keys(itemToCount).length;
    total += result;
    console.log(itemToCount, result, total);
    return total;
}

var count = dataSetOne.user.customers.reduce(function(total, current) {
    return counter(total, current.loads);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the right place to reset the variable. Just need to add  count = 0;  before every each loop and everything is working and looking much better. Thanks!